# Language Switcher - How to change link and make dynamic

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a language switcher to change between two languages Nederlands/English

I need the link to be changed whenever I'm on a page, like this

[www.example.nl/page/lorem](http://www.example.nl/page/lorem) to [www.example.nl/en/page/lorem](http://www.example.nl/en/page/lorem)

[www.example.nl/en/page/lorem](http://www.example.nl/en/page/lorem) to [www.example.nl/page/lorem](http://www.example.nl/page/lorem)

NOT

[www.example.nl/page/lorem](http://www.example.nl/page/lorem) to [www.example.nl/en/](http://www.example.nl/en/)

[www.example.nl/en/page/lorem](http://www.example.nl/en/page/lorem) to [www.example.nl/](http://www.example.nl/)

This is the code I'm using, but it doesn't work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winLocation = window.location;
    var loc = winLocation + "";
    if(loc.indexOf("/manasik_nl/en") != -1) {
       $(".lang").prop("href", loc.replace("/manasik_nl/en", "/manasik_nl/"));
       $(".lang").text("Nederlands");
    }
    else if(loc.indexOf("/manasik_nl/") != -1) {
       $(".lang").prop("href", loc.replace("/manasik_nl/", "/manasik_nl/en"));
       $(".lang").text("English");
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="language-switcher">
<a class="lang" href="/manasik_nl/" language="English"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-110" src="https://manasik.nl/manasik_nl/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/nl.png" alt="" width="18" height="12" /></a>
<a class="lang" href="/manasik_nl/en/" language="Nederlands"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-109" src="https://manasik.nl/manasik_nl/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/en.png"  alt="" width="18" height="12" /></a></div>
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this html code example:

```
<select id="languages">
      <option id='1' value="English" placeholder='English'>
      <option id='2' value="Nederlands" placeholder='Nederlands'>
</select>
```

And add some JavaScript `onclick` function that switch from a page to another one with `window.location`.

```
document.getElementByID('1').onclick = function(){
      window.location.assign("your URL")
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want it to be a dropdown selection, is there a way to do it with the flag images that I already have?

Comment: Example of what I'm trying to do:
http://translation-demo-site.webflow.io/

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, you want to create 3 links with the href?